# Basics about action on a Scheme by finite Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes

Let $Y$ be a scheme and a finite group $G$ acts on $Y$ in the sense that $G$ embeds in
$Aut_{Sch}(Y)$ in category of schemes. I have two question concerning
general properties dealing with action by finite groups on schemes.

Let $T$ any other scheme and we consider the set $Hom(T, Y)$. Clearly
the action on $Y$ by $G$ induces naturally action on the set $Hom(T, Y)$
by $G$.

Question #1: Can we reconstruct the action on $G$ if we know completly how $G$ acts
on sets $Hom(T, Y)$ for *all* schemes $T$?

Now it's natural to ask when we can build the 'quotient' $Y/G$ and
when does it live also in category of schemes. The 'quotient' $Y/G$ satisfies following properties:

i) $p: Y \to Y/G$ is $G$ invariant

ii) every $G$-invariant morphism $Y \to T$ factors over $Y/G$.

I know that this always the case
if there exist open afine cover $Y= \cup V_i$ where every
$V_i= Spec(R_i)$ is $G$-invariant in the sense that the $G$-action by automorphisms
on $Y$ restricts for every $i$ to automorphism on $V_i$.
Then $G$ acts on every ring $R_i$ and we can build the invariant rings
$R_i^G \subset R_i$. It $G$ is finite and $R_i$ 'nice' then $R_i^G \subset R_i$
is finite.
Then we can define $Y/G$ by glueing the affine schemes $U_i= Spec(R_i^G)$ so
$Y/G$ is a scheme.

Question #2: Can we here go 'backwards'? So assume that we know
that the quotient $Y/G$ is a scheme, can we find an afine cover
$Y= \cup V_i$ where every $V_i= Spec(R_i)$ is $G$-invariant.

Comment: Q1. You may put $T=Spec(k)$, where $k$ is any algebraically closed field and thus know the action on the level of points. You may put $T = Y$, and then looking at where the $id_Y \in Hom(Y, Y)$ go to under the action of, we can understand how does $G$ act on $Y$. This seems to suggest yes as the answer to your question 1.

Comment: Q2. Choose an affine open cover of $Y/G$ say $U_i$. Then $p^{-1}(U_i)$ is an open cover of $Y$. Now, since $G$ is a finite cover, then the map $p$ is finite and hence $p^{-1}(U_i)$ is affine. It is clear that $G$ acts on $p^{-1}(U_i)$ since the map $p$ is $G$-invariant.

Comment: Re Q1: So you claim in second part that we can understand 
the action
of $G$ on $Y$ by consider the orbit of $id_Y$ under action of
$G$ on $Hom(Y,Y)$. Understand in which sense? In sense of a 'complete' recover,
so a '1-to-1' recover or do we
lose some information? I mean first of all why 
is every image of $id_Y$ in $Hom(Y,Y)$ by $G$-action an
isomorphism and not just a usual morphism?

Comment: Re Q2: Ok, so here we have to assume that $G$ is *finite*,
otherwise $p^{-1}(U_i)$ may be not affine, right? 
My concern is if the finiteness assumption on $G$ can be relaxed
in that way that we still have that $p^{-1}(U_i)$. If $G$ is finite, then
$p^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is *finite* map, so affine. But of course 
there exist affine, but not finite maps. So it seems that at all
we exploit only that $p^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is affine, but 
not that it is quasi-finite.

Comment: so the question is if there is a bigger class of groups than only the finite 
groups known such that
$p^{-1}(U_i)$ stays nevertheless affine?